# NavigationView change selected item using back button

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm using a navigationview control in a UWP app, the thing is when I click the back button the focused element doesn't change to the item displayed in the contentframe. For example the clicked elements were camara, store, musica, then back button twice to display camara in the contentframe element, but musica still has the focus (blue rectangle)

```
private void FrameNavigated( object sender, NavigationEventArgs e )
    {
        var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
        if ( ContentFrame.CanGoBack )
        {
            currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

private void OnBackRequested( object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( ContentFrame.CanGoBack )
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            PageStackEntry pageStackEntry = ContentFrame.BackStack.LastOrDefault();

            ContentFrame.GoBack();

            if ( pageStackEntry != null )
            {
                string nombre = pageStackEntry.SourcePageType.Name;
                MenuItem item = subItemsMenu.FirstOrDefault(nom => nom.NombrePantalla.Equals(nombre));

                navView.SelectedItem = item;
                navView.Header = item.Encabezado;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, using 
NavigationViewExtensions.SetSelectedIndex(NavigationView, index); from Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions 4.0.0, since 5.0.0 version is deprecated

Comment: If you have resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any problem in your code. Several ways may help to troubleshooting:

1. Debug and make sure MenuItem item is not null.
2. When back button is clicked, try select home or camera directly by your code

   private void OnBackRequested( object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e )
   { 
     string nombre = "Camera";
     MenuItem item = subItemsMenu.FirstOrDefault(nom => nom.NombrePantalla.Equals(nombre));
     navView.SelectedItem = item;
   }
3. Add SelectionChanged="nav_SelectionChanged" to the XAML and then check [SelectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.SelectionChanged)
4. Post a simple app which can repro your problem